# Problem in getting coefficients list of power series solution of y''[x]*y'[InverseFunction[y][x]] - y'[x] == 0?

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, coefficients

I have tried to get solution of the following ODE:

```
y''[x]*y'[InverseFunction[y][x]] - y'[x] == 0
```

Using the code given below, the solution is a formal power series around 0 satisfying `y[0] == 0`, I want to get the coefficient list of this formal power series which are:`{0, 1, 1/2, 0, 1/24, -1/20, 13/180, -197/1680, 2101/10080, -48203/120960, 2938057/3628800, -23059441/13305600, 74408941/19160064, -9409883317/1037836800}`.

I ran the code below, but I got only the form of the series but for coefficients list I didn't get the expected result. Thank you for any help.

```
**Code**
ode = y''[x]*y'[InverseFunction[y][x]] - y'[x] == 0;
initconds = {y[0] == 0};
odeOperator = 
  D[#, {x, 2}]*D[#, x][ InverseFunction[y][x]] - D[#, x] &;
yy = Series[y[x], {x, 0, 10}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to do this is to start with an ansatz (note that the OP has neglected to explicitly declare the `y'[0] == 1` condition):

```
n = 12;
ansatz = x + Sum[C[k] x^k, {k, 2, n}] + O[x]^(n + 1)
```

and then use `InverseSeries[]` for inversion, and `ComposeSeries[]` for composition, before using `SolveAlways[]` to get the needed coefficients:

```
ansatz /. First[SolveAlways[D[ansatz, {x, 2}]
                            ComposeSeries[D[ansatz, x], InverseSeries[ansatz]] -
                            D[ansatz, x] == 0, x]]
   x + x^2/2 + x^4/24 - x^5/20 + (13 x^6)/180 - (197 x^7)/1680 +
   (2101 x^8)/10080 - (48203 x^9)/120960 + (2938057 x^10)/3628800 -
   (23059441 x^11)/13305600 + (74408941 x^12)/19160064 + O[x]^13
```

Comment: Interesting type of DE.  Thanks for solution.  Looks like could have used y'[0]=a and then sub a x+c2 x^2+...

Comment: Indeed, that would yield the generic solution, but the coefficient set supplied/expected by the OP implicitly defined that free parameter. ;)